# Building a deeply nested boolean object with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nested-object

I'm trying to build a boolean block that can be N levels deep, and update the blocks as needed. I started looking into using Lodash ._update, but it seems you need to know the exact path, and this breaks if i have an array of objects.

Basically, i have something like this:

```
 let obj  {
     and: [{id: 1}]
   }
```

Using Lodash i want to do somethiing like:

```
let s = {id: 4}
._update(obj, 'a.or', s, (n) => n ? [...n, ...s] : [s]

result: {and: [{id: 3}, {or: [{id: 4]]}]
```

However this doesn't work because it can't find the path.

If I do this:

```
._update(obj, 'a[0].or', s, (n) => n ? [...n, ...s] : [s]
```

I get this  `{ and: [{id: 2, or: [{id: 4}] } ] }`

What ends up working for me is this:

```
._update(obj, 'a[1].or', s, (n) => n ? [...n, ...s] : [s]
```

My problem is I won't know how many total items are in the `and: []`, so I'd like to make this more dynamic. I suppose I could fetch the value at `and` and get the length, but I think this will break when I have to go deeper into the object.

If anyone has done something like this, could you point me to some references?

Comment: I assume you mean `_.update`

Comment: @epascarello excellent assumption